# What properties do L2 functions have other than going to zero in infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, hilbert-spaces

Reading some Quantum Mechanics, I encountered essentially the following claim: Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} \ $ where $f \in L_2$  (an square-integrable function integrated over $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$);
then, $$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} xf^*(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$
not only exists, but it is zero. I know from Barbalat's lemma that why $f(x)$ and $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ should go to zero in infinity, however, we have them both multiplied by $x$ itself blowing up which is an indeterminate case of $0 \cdot \infty$.

Are there any additional properties to have in mind when working with such functions in the limiting cases?

Edit 1: $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$.

Comment: What is $f^*$? If it is just $f$ itself, then the assertion that $f(x)$ goes to $0$ at infinity is false (thinner-but-higher, smooth spikes marching out to infinity), and $df/dx$ also does not go to $0$, and their product does not... much less when multiplied by $x$... Have you written what you intended?

Comment: What is QM?  Quantum mechanics?  (Then take math claims with a grain of salt...)

Comment: @paulgarrett I fixed the conditions, I forgot to include the bounds.

Comment: No such pointwise estimate is even remotely true under the mere assumption that a function is $ L^2 $.  Don't trust your source in this case.  See the example outlined by paul garrett in the comments.  It's possible, though I haven't checked, that the author could be referring to a Sobolev space like $ W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) $.

Comment: @JakeMirra, yes, on the line, functions in $W^{1,2}$ do have some decay. Not clear to me that multiplication by $x$ wouldn't overwhelm it, though. I'd have to do a computation...

Answer (score 1):

As people have basically pointed out in the comments, the claim is false.

A first problem is, that the derivative $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ does not need to exist.

Even if we assume that it exists (or exists in a weak sense),
one could construct a counterexample
by using spikes $g_n$ which are active near $n\in\Bbb N\subset Bbb R$
and whose contribution to the $L_2$-norm of the function is exponentially small,
for example $\|g_n\|_{L_2}\leq 2^{-n}$.